# Updated gulp to gulp 4 but can't figure out how to make simple-task-loader work

Tags: node.js, gulp, migrate, gulp-watch, gulp-task

First of all, this may seem a dumb/noob question, but I'm more of a backend developer and I don't really work with npm and node that often. I was just used to start gulp watch and I was ready to go theming/styling.

So i just upgraded to gulp 4 with node version 10. Ofcourse i'm getting the `Task never defined: default` error. So i'm trying to migrate to gulp 4's way of defining tasks, but i can't just make it work with simple-task-loader. When i try a sample code, i'm getting gulp not defined. Here is the original old code gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var taskLoader = require('gulp-simple-task-loader');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var config = require('./config.json');

    taskLoader({
        taskDirectory: 'bower_components/gulp-tasks/tasks',
        plugins: plugins,
        config: config
    });
```

And this is the default.js and watch.js from simple-task-loader

default.s:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(gulp, config, plugins) {
        return function() {
        return gulp.start(config.default_tasks);
        };
};
```

watch.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(gulp, config, plugins) {
        return function() {
        config.production = false;
                plugins.livereload.listen();
        gulp.start(config.default_tasks);
        config.default_tasks.forEach(function(task) {
                        if (config[task].watch) {
                                gulp.watch(config[task].watch, [task]);
                        } else {
                                gulp.watch(config[task].src, [task]);
                        }
        })
        return true;
        };
};
```

When trying to use the new default.js code, I'm getting gulp not defined even though in the main gulpfile.js there is a require.

example new default.js:

```
exports.default = gulp.series(parallel(gulp, config, plugins));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('start'));
```

Will return gulp not defined

Comment: If you are just wanting to do a "watch", why are you upgrading gulp? I've been through that, and it is not always easy.

Comment: I messed up with a nodeJS project so i upgraded everything